# Is it possible to intricate pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers

Something recently hyped my curiosity while coding : is it possible to intricate pointers in C ?
I explain: I would like to link two pointers, let's say two int * p1 and p2. The idea is, whenever I edit the value of p1, the value of p2 is also edited. Example :

- `*p1 = 2`
  and I want for instance that `*p2 = *p1-1`;
- `*p1=3;`.
  But here `*p2` still amounts to 1... Is there a way to make `*p2` equals to `*p1 - 1` every time, without having to edit the value of `*p2` after every modification of `*p1` ?

Not having to edit intricated pointers every time.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is no.

There isn't "magic under the hood" with pointers.
I know that, when beginning, it may seems so. Because of the apparent magic of things like

```c
int x=12;
int *y=&x;

*y=15; // Wow, value of x has changed
```

But in reality those are really rudimentary things. With absolutely no other operation than the plain operations we wrote. `y` is the "address" of `x`. `*y=15` changes what is at address `y`, that is, since this is the value of y, what it at the address of `x`. So it changes `x`.

It is not like in higher level languages, such as python, or even C++, where you could have redefined affectation operators, or things like that, so that the simple fact of saying `*y=15` does way more things than changing what is at address `y`, but also affects other values. Understand that something will have to computes `15-1` to do what you want. Those computations have to be done somewhere. In higher level languages, they could be implicit, because you said, somehow, that `=` implies many such computations. But in low-level language, the only computations that occurs are the one you explicitly coded.

So, again, short answer: no, not in C.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use separate pointers but pointer arithmetic:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int array [3] = {1,2,3};
  int* p1 = &array[1];
  const int offset = -1;
  printf("p1: %d p2: %d\n", *p1, p1[offset]);

  p1 = &array[2];
  printf("p1: %d p2: %d\n", *p1, p1[offset]);
}
```

This is fine and well-defined as long as the offset doesn't lead to an out of bounds access.

Answer (score 1):

If `p1` and `p2` are two different pointer objects pointing to the same object:

```
    +---+
p1: |   | -----+
    +---+      |     +---+
               +---> |   |
    +---+      |     +---+
p2: |   | -----+
    +---+
```

then writing to `*p1` (note the dereference) is the same as writing to `*p2` - either one will update the pointed-to object.  But, `p1` and `p2` are completely separate objects themselves, so changing the value of `p1` (no dereference) has absolutely no effect on `p2` or vice-versa.

C doesn't give you a way to automagically update the value of one object when another object's value is changed.  You have to write the code to keep the values of `p1` and `p2` in sync.